# i am getting a error when processing json data from a website and adding it to a mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, json

Hi all i am running my python file to get data form a api and putting it in to a mysql database from json, i have used the code before the onlything that changed in where the data is comming from i have chaged the id names to make sure they are correct

> the error is Traceback (most recent call last):   File "bne.py", line
>   35, in 
>       for element in response_data['flightData']: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

here is my code

```
import urllib.parse
import requests
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="*****",
  database="flightdata"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()




url = 'https://www.bne.com.au/sites/default/files/00API-Today.json?nocache=true'


#address = 'true'
#url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({address: address})

response_data = requests.get(url).json()
# empty list for holding all the data
data = []
for element in response_data['flightData']:
    origin = ['Brisbane']
    flight_id = element['id']
    airline = element['AirlineName']
    destination = element['ToFrom']
    flightNumbers = element['FlightNumber']
    scheduledTime = element['ScheduledTimeTime']
    estimatedTime = element['EstimatedTimeTime']
    scheduledDate = element['ScheduledTimeEuro']
    latestTime = element['EstimatedTimeTime']
    status = element['status']
    print (origin, flight_id, flightNumbers, airline, destination, scheduledTime, scheduledDate, latestTime, status)

    sql = "INSERT INTO flightinfo (origin, id, airline, destinations, flightNumbers, scheduledTime, estimatedTime, scheduledDate, latestTime, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

    val = ('sydney', flight_id, airline, " ".join(destination), ", ".join(flightNumbers), scheduledTime, estimatedTime,
            scheduledDate, latestTime, status)
    data.append(val)


# doing a batch insert
mycursor.executemany(sql, data)

#mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.")


#print(val)
#print(pd.datetime.now().date())
```

Comment: I tried to fetch the passed url, `https://www.bne.com.au/sites/default/files/00API-Today.json?nocache=true`and didn't found the `flightData` on it

Comment: `response_data` is a list, not a dictionary. You should be getting an error for `response_data['flightData']`

Comment: Why are you putting Sydney as the origin of all the flights, instead of using the actual `DepartureAirportName`?

Comment: just a test for the sydney name to see if ti worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

response_data is a list containing the dict(s) you are looking for. 
If you go through the list with:

```
for element in response_data:
    airline = element['Airline']
```

element should contain the dict you want.

Comment: i get a error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bne.py", line 37, in <module>
    flight_id = element['id']
KeyError: 'id'

G:\My Drive\ADBY Projects\ADBY PROJECTS\Flight Check>

Comment: Thats probably, because the returned data does not contain a ke "id". Start the project with a debugger, set a breakpoint after getting response_data and look at its content. That could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for element in response_data:
   ....
```

instead of,

```
for element in response_data['flightData']:
   ...
```

The response from json is a `list` of `dict` not a `dict`